# Not able to access Kubernetes service among nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have two services- Tomcat and Mysql. Tomcat is front facing and hence I am using node port for that but for the mysql container, I am using Cluster Ip type for service.

I have multiple nodes in Kuberntes cluster and multiple replicas of tomcat. When tomcat container is coming in the master node, It is working fine, But when spawned on other nodes, It is failing as it is not able to make a connection to other services.

Can anyone please help with this how to provide the endpoint here so that Tomcat will able to make a connection to MySQL service through JDBC.

Currently, I am referencing services using service name itself.

**Error -

I am accessing the db through db hostname and jdbc url, I am getting unkown host error.**

Comment: Where do you get the URL for your database? You can inject via env vars which works within the same namespace or use k8 dns so it would be available via <service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local

Comment: Yes. already did that. tried the same. It is working only if pod is in master node. Otherwise it is not working

Comment: What is the URL you are using to reach the database? How did you deploy the cluster? User pods don't get to run on the master node

Comment: My db hostname is mysqlservice2.default.svc.cluster.local:3306. And I am deploying it as Cluster ip service through yaml.  We can run  user pods on master nodes as well. for that need to taint the master node using kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

Comment: I'd try these tips https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use statefulset for MySQL and "none" as clusterIp.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    name: server
  selector:
    app: mysql
```